# Trying to create an EJB Project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, ejb

I am following the tutorial at this link: http://programming.manessinger.com/tutorials/an-eclipse-glassfish-java-ee-6-tutorial/, but instead using JBoss instead of GlassFish. I am basically trying to learn Java EE concepts like EJB, Hibernate and JPA.

However, I am stuck on the part for creating an EJB Project in Eclipse. I am supposed to add this to the EAR project, but I cannot find the EJB Project as a selection for new project. I went through the entire list, and it simply is not there. All I see are options for creating EJB Message and Session beans.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Also, if anyone knows any really great tutorials on creating projects to get a handle on these JEE concepts, please pass them forward!

Answer (score 1):

The EJB project must not be created inside the EAR project. Eclipse doesn't have the notiopon of projects inside a project. You create a new top-level EJB project (File - New - EJB - EJB Project), and in its settings, you declare it's part of the other EAR project.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion on that. I am trying to create a top level project, then declare it as part of the EAR. But I don't see it.

I'm going to File->New->Project and searching through all possible projects and not finding it.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification that an EAR project is just a big wrapper around EJB projects, Dynamic Web Projects, and ?JPA projects.  Do I have that right? This point is not at all obvious for Eclipse newbies.